# in Unix program how to compare two strings in a same file?

Tags: unit-testing, shell, unix

Hi i have to write one program in unix ,this program should compare two strings in a same file, 
file contains below these two strings along with other data which is of no use in this program,
i have to check in the file if the no (eg 16) is matched in both strings or not.

```
Validating 16 transactions.
Rows valid: 16.
```

giving error

```
1.prog: line 5: Validating: command not found
1.prog: line 6: Rows valid: command not found
1.prog: line 7: GRP1: command not found


NOT DONE
1.prog: line 11: =: command not found
```

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
POINT='.'
for FILE in $HOME/l26026363.txt
do
  GRP1=grep "Validating" $FILE |cut -d' ' -f2
  GRP2=grep "Rows valid" $FILE |cut -d' ' -f3
  GRP1 =$GRP1$POINT
  echo $GRP1
  echo $GRP2 
  echo NOT DONE 
  if $GRP1 = $GRP2
   then  echo "IN IF"
   #mv FILE /home/appltest/test_dir
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` statement should be along the lines of:

```
if [[ $GRP1 -eq $GRP2 ]]
```

(there are a few variations depending on which shell you're actually using but I think that ones probably the most portable - use the manpages for your given shell to find out the correct format if that doesn't work).

`if` takes a *command* and checks the return value from it. If the first argument you give it is not a command (for example, an enviroment variable which translates to a non-command), it will try to run that as a command and fail.

---

Here's a transcript of a `bash` script:

```
pax$ cat qq.bash
#!/bin/bash

GRP1=$(expr 22 + 3)
GRP2=$(expr 100 / 4)
GRP3=$(expr 75 - 5)

if [[ $GRP1 -eq $GRP2 ]] ; then
    echo "GRP1 and GRP2 are equal ($GRP1)"
else
    echo "GRP1 and GRP2 are unequal ($GRP1, $GRP2)"
fi

if [[ $GRP1 -eq $GRP3 ]] ; then
    echo "GRP1 and GRP3 are equal ($GRP1)"
else
    echo "GRP1 and GRP3 are unequal ($GRP1, $GRP3)"
fi

pax$ ./qq.bash
GRP1 and GRP2 are equal (25)
GRP1 and GRP3 are unequal (25, 70)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the if statement explained in another answer, when assigning a variable in shell by calling another command, you must backquote it:

```
GRP1=`grep "Validating" $FILE |cut -d' ' -f2`
GRP2=`grep "Rows valid" $FILE |cut -d' ' -f3`
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use grep multiple times. Its a waste of processes. Use awk

```
for....
do    
    awk -vfile=$FILE '/Validating/{s1=$2}/Rows valid/{s2=$NF+0}
    END{
        if ( s1==s2 ){
          cmd="mv "file" /home/appltest/test_dir"
          system(cmd)
        }
    }' $FILE
done
```